# Maharal on Eruv Tavshilin

Tags: sources-mekorot, olam-haba-world-to-come, eruv-tavshilin, maharal, ymoth-hamoshiach

I'm trying to find a Maharal on Eruv Tavshilin in which he explains that *olam hazeh* (this world) is symbolized by the regular weekday embodied in *erev yom tov* (the eve of the holiday) in which one "prepares" (i.e. earn merit) for *olam haba* (the world to come), as symbolized by *Shabbath*.  *Yemoth hamashiach* (the messianic era) is symbolized by the *yom tov* (holiday) itself, in which one can continue to prepare for "*Shabbath*" provided one has already begun to prepare during "*erev yom tov*".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least one instance is in [Netzach Yisrael Ch. 46](https://www.sefaria.org/Netzach_Yisrael.46.4?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en):

> ויש לפרש כי זה ענין מצות עירוב תבשילין, שיום טוב הסמוך לשבת מניח עירוב תבשילין מבעוד יום קודם יום טוב, ואז אף ביום טוב יכול לתקן מאכלו לשבת. כי מה שצריך לתקן סעודות שבת קודם שבת, רמז הוא שהשבת מענין עולם הבא, ומי שטרח בערב שבת יאכל בשבת, ומי שלא טרח בערב שבת מה יאכל [ע"ז ג ע"א]. ויום טוב הסמוך לשבת, הם ימים טובים שיש לאדם, כמו ימי המשיח, וכל ימים טובים שיש לאדם. ואז לא יבשל בתחלה בהן לשבת, שאין יום טוב מכין לשבת (ביצה ב ע"ב), שיהיה מתקן בו - בימות המשיח שהם ימים טובים, או שאר ימים טובים שיש לאדם - לא יכול לתקן מה שיאכל לעולם הבא. שזה אינו, שאם מקיים מצות ומעשים בשביל שיש לו הרבה טובות, והוא מקיים מצוות, אין זה כלום. לכך אין מבשלין מתחלה מיום טוב לשבת. וכמו שאמר הכתוב על איוב שהיה "ירא אלקים" (איוב א, ח), אמר השטן (איוב א, ט-יא) "החנם איוב ירא אלקים הלא אתה שכת בעדו ובעד ביתו ובעד כל אשר לו מסביב מעשה ידיו ברכת מקנהו פרץ בארץ ואולם שלח נא ידך וגו'". ולפיכך האדם אם הוא צדיק מפני הטוב, אין זה דבר. ולכך אין מתקנין מיום טוב לסעודת שבת. רק אם התחיל לבשל לפני יום טוב - הוא מבשל אף ביום טוב, שזה מוכח שלא בשביל יום טוב הוא מבשל לשבת - עד שלא יהיה רשאי לבשל מתחלה לשבת - שהרי התחיל כבר לפני יום טוב.

(Hattip: https://www.halachabrura.org/agada/betza02-15.htm )